# mongoexport works but mongo shell fails on mlab

Tags: mongodb, shell, authentication

I have a mongo db setup on mlab for use with meteor running on Galaxy.  I can succesfully export from this database using mongoexport on my windows 8.1 64-bit laptop. I also want to connect with the mongo shell, but I get "not authorized" error messages, using the exact same mongo user and password.

In more detail - this works just fine, using mongoexport version r3.4.7:

```
mongoexport --host ds121225.mlab.com:21225 -d quarule-db01 --collection Quarule -u xxxxx -p xxxx -q "{vocabularyName: 'qre'}" --out QRE.json
```

while this fails:

```
mongo ds121225.mlab.com:21225/quarule-db01 -u xxxx -p xxxxx
MongoDB shell version v3.4.7
connecting to: mongodb://ds121225.mlab.com:21225/quarule-db01
MongoDB server version: 3.4.9
rs-ds121225:PRIMARY> show dbs
2017-10-30T19:50:37.795-0700 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: listDatabases failed:{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1.0 }",
    "code" : 13,
    "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
Mongo.prototype.getDBs@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:62:1
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:769:19
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:659:15
```

I have checked and rechecked that I am specifying the userid and password the same way in both commands.

Why would the export succeed and the shell fail?

Comment: pass --authenticationDatabase=quarule-db01

Comment: Because commonly assigned roles such as [`readWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#readWrite) or even just [`read`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#read) which are sufficient for "exporting" simply do not contain the [`listDatabases`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#listDatabases) privilege. Details on the linked pages about what is actually applied.

Comment: I think Neil Lunn is right.  I find that other Mongo shell commands such as "show collections" and "db.Quarule.find({}) work fine.  Checking the mlab admin pages, I find that the userid I am using has the "dbOwner" role.  According to the mongdb doc, that role does not include the "listdatabases" role.  Sheesh.

Comment: So now the question is how do I add additional roles to the database user on mlab.  I can't see a way to do it.

Comment: mlab support says: "If you're using a Sandbox database, server level commands such as show dbs will not work because you only have access to your particular database on the shared Sandbox server. If you get the PRIMARY> prompt in the shell, that means you successfully connected to your database, so database level commands such as show collections should work at that point."  So if you're using the free "sandbox" mlab service, don't expect the standard mongo shell "show dbs" to work.  Even though (for me, at least) it's the very first thing I try when I'm using the shell to debug problems.